# Meaning of "Having one foot in and one foot out wouldn't work"

Tags: meaning, sentence

What does it mean?

In an interview with Gayle King, Ivanka told her:

> When I spoke to “60 Minutes” it was I think five or six days following the election. And I was processing real time the new reality and what it would mean … **I realized that having one foot in and one foot out wouldn’t work.** … And the reality is that it all happened very organically for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means, simply, that being partially involved would not be successful.  She's saying that she had to be "all in".  Trying to be a part-time advisor to the president would lead to failure.  If she was going to help her father, she had to commit to it fully.

I suspect she was making an allusion to the song/dance [*The Hokey Pokey*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hokey_cokey) where, at least in the US version, you "put your right foot in, you put your right foot out," etc.

Comment: Thank u for ur reply. Informative and really Interesting:)